# How to import urls from folder

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, microsoft-edge, bookmarks

I am trying to find how to import file from a saved/backedup favorites folder.

Most import method like this one
https://www.wikihow.com/Import-Favorites only import from another browser.

What if I have a folder on my computer with its folder structures and hundreds of .url file saved.

From the look of it, it was a favorite folder saved/backed up from another computer.

Can this be imported in browser as bookmarks all in one go or I have to visit each and saved as bookmark once opened in browser?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You had asked,"**What if I have a folder on my computer with its folder structures and hundreds of .url file saved.**"

All the latest browsers supports .HTML file to import bookmarks.

I can see that you are using .URL file.

So you can not import the bookmarks from .URL file and you need to find a way convert your .URL files in to .HTML files.

***In Edge, You can refer steps below to import bookmarks from file.***

(1) Click on Settings.

(2) Click on 'Import from another browser' button.

(3) Click on 'Import from File' button.

(4) Select .HTML file from dialog.

(5) Click on OK.

**In Chrome, You can refer steps below.**

(1) Click on Settings.

(2) Click on 'Import bookmarks and setting' option.

(3) Select option 'Bookmarks HTML file' from dropdown.

(4) Click on 'Choose file' button.

(5) Select .HTML file from dialog.

(6) Click on OK.

**Similar kind of option you can get in Internet Explorer to import bookmarks from file.**

[How to import and export the Internet Explorer Favorites folder to a 32-bit version of Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/211089/how-to-import-and-export-the-internet-explorer-favorites-folder-to-a-3)

Regards

Deepak

Comment: I want to import folders containing many bookmarks including its structures. not single files. hundreds.

Comment: As I inform you before, At present all famous browsers support .HTML files to import bookmarks. It cannot import bookmark from .URL file. So if you have .URL files then I did not get anyway to import from it.

Comment: .url is not the problem here. I can convert all those to .html. the problem is the process. `Select .html file from dialog.` I have to repeat that several times? How can it create the same structures that I have?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to create a single HTML file when you convert it from .URL file.

Or you can try to refer shellScript below may help you to import bookmarks in MS Edge from folder.

```js
$EdgeFavoritesPath = "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\AC\MicrosoftEdge\User\Default\Favorites" 
 
If(Test-Path -Path $FavoritesPath) 
{ 
    If($PSCmdlet.ShouldProcess("$EdgeFavoritesPath","Copy '$FavoritesPath'")) 
    { 
        Write-Verbose "Copying the favorites to Edge browser." 
        Copy-Item -Path $FavoritesPath -Recurse -Destination $EdgeFavoritesPath -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
    } 
     
    New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT | Out-Null 
    $RegKeypPath = "HKCR:\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\AppContainer\Storage\microsoft.microsoftedge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge\FavOrder" 
     
    #Chechk if the Favorder registry key really exists. 
    If(Test-Path -Path $RegKeypPath) 
    { 
        Write-Verbose "Deleting the FavOrder registry key." 
        Remove-Item -Path $RegKeypPath -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorVariable RemoveError 
        If($RemoveError.Exception -eq $null) 
        { 
            Write-Host "Successfully copied the favorites to Edge browser." 
        } 
        Else 
        { 
            Write-Host "Failed to copied the favorites of Edge browser." 
        } 
    } 
    Else 
    { 
        Write-Host "Successfully copied the favorites to Edge browser." 
    } 
}
```

Reference:

[How to copy the favorites to Windows 10 Edge browser](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/How-to-copy-the-favorites-06e55206)